# Webpack System.import() adds url pathname to the dynamic component request url

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router, webpack-2

I am using `"webpack": "^2.2.1"` and `react-router` routes for loading the component code dynamically when requested by the user.

I have specified the **publicPath: 'scripts/'** and everything seems to be working fine, the right files are generated, etc.

But in the app, If the user is not logged in, the app re-directs the user to the `/auth/login` page and this is where things take a wrong turn.

When loading components dynamically, If there's a path in url, That's appended in the url request as well, So `System.import` requests the right filename, except it contain `/pathname/` in the request and that causes the request to fail.

Example:

When the app loads at url `http://localhost:1337`, all the right script requests are make (since they are in html), But then the app redirects the user to `/auth/login` and since the Login component is loaded dynamically, a new request is made to `http://localhost:1337/auth/scripts/SCRIPTFILENAME.js`

And since there's no `auth/scripts/SCRIPTFILENAME.js` the request fails.

How can i get rid of the `auth` or any folder/subfolder/path from the url when requesting components dynamically